# css :target does not work on mozilla firefox

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to use the ':target' command on css to show a modal in my wordpress website. It works fine using chrome browser but if I use mozilla it doesn´t work. I only need change the 'opacity' property to 1 when whet ':target' is activaded.
This is the 'css' that I am using:

```
    .modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}



.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: can i see your html also?

Comment: [Firefox supports :target](http://caniuse.com/#search=:target) Your problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

this example works in mozilla firefox [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/txCiB)

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#h1">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#h2">link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h2 id="h1">link 1</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero eligendi, incidunt harum laborum ratione, labore quae modi hic est sint, aperiam corporis nesciunt dolor quasi iusto eaque itaque. Modi, deleniti.</p>
  <h2 id="h2">link 2</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint voluptates quia culpa, quos facilis, dicta reiciendis impedit deserunt a distinctio corporis in eos ipsum provident cum, dolorum dolorem tempore sapiente.</p>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
h2:target {
    background: #fc0; /* Цвет фона */
    padding: 3px; 
}
```